# Pivot multiple rows in SQL Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have data like below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(RuleName VARCHAR(100),
ParamValue VARCHAR(100),
ParamName VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Temp
VALUES ('BroadBandAviva','BroadBandAviva1','Rule Name'),
('BroadBandAviva','BroadBand','Expense Category name'),
('BroadBandAviva','DSF','org unit name'),
('BroadBandAviva','ASSISTANT SALES MANAGER','designation'),
('BroadBandAviva','Category   A','cityclassification'),
('BroadBandAviva','2000','Eligible Amount'),
('BroadBandAviva','BroadBandAviva2','Rule Name'),
('BroadBandAviva','BroadBand','Expense Category name'),
('BroadBandAviva','DSF','org unit name'),
('BroadBandAviva','ASSISTANT SALES MANAGER','designation'),
('BroadBandAviva','ROI-Rest   of India','cityclassification'),
('BroadBandAviva','2000','Eligible Amount')
```

and I want the output like this:

```
RuleName    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BroadBandAviva  Rule Name   Expense Category name   org unit name   designation cityclassification  Eligible Amount
BroadBandAviva  BroadBandAviva1 BroadBand   DSF ASSISTANT SALES MANAGER Category   A    2000
BroadBandAviva  BroadBandAviva2 BroadBand   DSF ASSISTANT SALES MANAGER ROI-Rest   of India 2000
```

Basically the first column should stay as it is, third column should become the first row and the second column should come in second row onwards. I tried with pivot function but I could not get the desired output.

Comment: *"I tried with pivot function"* Can you please post it?

Comment: Is the design of this fixed? it isn't "query friendly"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach which places the values into separate columns, like this:

```
|       RULENAME | GRPNO |            COL1 |                  COL2 |          COL3 |                    COL4 |                COL5 |            COL6 |
|----------------|-------|-----------------|-----------------------|---------------|-------------------------|---------------------|-----------------|
| BroadBandAviva |    -1 |       Rule Name | Expense Category name | org unit name |             designation |  cityclassification | Eligible Amount |
| BroadBandAviva |     0 | BroadBandAviva1 |             BroadBand |           DSF | ASSISTANT SALES MANAGER |        Category   A |            2000 |
| BroadBandAviva |     1 | BroadBandAviva2 |             BroadBand |           DSF | ASSISTANT SALES MANAGER | ROI-Rest   of India |            2000 |
```

Like my previous attempt I use a CTE to retain some needed calculations that are reused in a subsequent union. Unlike the previous attempt though I use conventional `case expressions` and `group by` to achieve the pivot. Here is the query.

```
declare @i int = (select count(distinct ParamName) from Temp)

;with cte as (
select 
        *
      , row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as rn
      , (row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1) / @i as grpno
      , row_number() over(order by (select 1)) % @i as prow
from temp
)
select
        rulename
      , -1 as grpno
      , max(case when prow = 1 then paramname end) as col1
      , max(case when prow = 2 then paramname end) as col2
      , max(case when prow = 3 then paramname end) as col3
      , max(case when prow = 4 then paramname end) as col4
      , max(case when prow = 5 then paramname end) as col5
      , max(case when prow = 0 then paramname end) as col6
from cte
WHERE rn <= @i
group by
        rulename

union all

select
        rulename
      , grpno
      , max(case when prow = 1 then paramvalue end) as col1
      , max(case when prow = 2 then paramvalue end) as col2
      , max(case when prow = 3 then paramvalue end) as col3
      , max(case when prow = 4 then paramvalue end) as col4
      , max(case when prow = 5 then paramvalue end) as col5
      , max(case when prow = 0 then paramvalue end) as col6
from cte
group by
        rulename
      , grpno

;
```

To follow the logic it is useful to understand the columns `PROW` (parameter row) and `GRPNO` (grouping number), here is the CTE contents showing those columns:

```
/*
|       RULENAME |              PARAMVALUE |             PARAMNAME | RN | GRPNO | PROW |
|----------------|-------------------------|-----------------------|----|-------|------|
| BroadBandAviva |         BroadBandAviva1 |             Rule Name |  1 |     0 |    1 |
| BroadBandAviva |               BroadBand | Expense Category name |  2 |     0 |    2 |
| BroadBandAviva |                     DSF |         org unit name |  3 |     0 |    3 |
| BroadBandAviva | ASSISTANT SALES MANAGER |           designation |  4 |     0 |    4 |
| BroadBandAviva |            Category   A |    cityclassification |  5 |     0 |    5 |
| BroadBandAviva |                    2000 |       Eligible Amount |  6 |     0 |    0 |
| BroadBandAviva |         BroadBandAviva2 |             Rule Name |  7 |     1 |    1 |
| BroadBandAviva |               BroadBand | Expense Category name |  8 |     1 |    2 |
| BroadBandAviva |                     DSF |         org unit name |  9 |     1 |    3 |
| BroadBandAviva | ASSISTANT SALES MANAGER |           designation | 10 |     1 |    4 |
| BroadBandAviva |     ROI-Rest   of India |    cityclassification | 11 |     1 |    5 |
| BroadBandAviva |                    2000 |       Eligible Amount | 12 |     1 |    0 |
*/
```

<kbd>[see the SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6eb49/1)</kbd>

Comment: can you please help on this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/25622477/2709770

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as I can get, maybe others can use it? note the `2000` below is in the wrong place and I cannot see why or how.

```
|       RULENAME |  PARAMS                                                                                            |
|----------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| BroadBandAviva |  Rule Name, Expense Category name, org unit name, designation, cityclassification, Eligible Amount |
| BroadBandAviva |        BroadBandAviva1, BroadBand, DSF, ASSISTANT SALES MANAGER, Category   A                      |
| BroadBandAviva |  2000, BroadBandAviva2, BroadBand, DSF, ASSISTANT SALES MANAGER, ROI-Rest   of India               |
                    ^^^^^
```

Here's the query I used:

```
declare @i int = (select count(distinct ParamName) from Temp)

;with cte as (
select 
        *
      , row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as rn
      , row_number() over(order by (select 1)) / @i as grpno
      , row_number() over(order by (select 1)) % @i as prow
from temp
)

SELECT
        (select RuleName from cte where rn = 1) as RULENAME
      , STUFF((
              SELECT
                    ', ' + c2.ParamName
              FROM CTE as c2
              WHERE rn <= @i
              order by c2.rn
              FOR XML PATH ('')
              )
             , 1, 1, '') as PARAMS
         --, -1, -1, -1

UNION ALL

select
      cte.RuleName
    , caxml.params
       --, cte.grpno, prow, rn
from cte
CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT
              STUFF((
                    SELECT
                          ', ' + c2.ParamValue
                    FROM CTE as c2
                    WHERE c2.grpno = cte.grpno
                    order by case when c2.prow = @i then @i else c2.prow end
                    FOR XML PATH ('')
                    )
                   , 1, 1, '')
         ) caxml (params)
where prow = 1
;
```

<kbd>[see SQLFiddle Demo for more](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/620fa/33)</kbd>

Comment: i don't want the rest of the columns concatenated in one column as you have done in PARAMS column. All the comma separated items should come in different columns. 2000 is the value that should be obtained in the last column i.e. Eligible Amount.

Comment: Forgive me, but once into comma separated state (assuming they are in the right position) THEN you could achieve the differing columns.  Are the number of rows to columns variable (I have assumed they are). This is not a good data design - can you alter this?