# To club the rows for week days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have data like below:

```
StartDate     EndDate    Duration 
----------
41890         41892       3
41898         41900       3
41906         41907       2
41910         41910       1
```

StartDate and EndDate are respective ID values for any dates from calendar. I want to calculate the sum of duration for consecutive days. Here I want to include the days which are weekends. E.g. in the above data, let's say 41908 and 41909 are weekends, then my required result set should look like below.

I already have another proc that can return me the next working day, i.e. if I pass 41907 or 41908 or 41909 as DateID in that proc, it will return 41910 as the next working day. Basically I want to check if the DateID returned by my proc when I pass the above EndDateID is same as the next StartDateID from above data, then both the rows should be clubbed. Below is the data I want to get.

```
ID          StartDate     EndDate    Duration 
----------
278457        41890       41892       3
278457        41898       41900       3
278457        41906       41910       3
```

Please let me know in case the requirement is not clear, I can explain further.

My Date Table is like below:

```
DateId        Date      Day
----------
41906      09-04-2014    Thursday
41907      09-05-2014    Friday
41908      09-06-2014    Saturdat
41909      09-07-2014    Sunday
41910      09-08-2014    Monday
```

Here is the SQL Code for setup:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
StartDate INT,
EndDate INT,
LeaveDuration INT
)

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES(41890, 41892, 3),
(41898, 41900, 3),
(41906, 41907, 3),
(41910, 41910, 1)

CREATE TABLE DateTable
(
DateID INT,
Date DATETIME,
Day VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO DateTable
VALUES(41907, '09-05-2014', 'Friday'),
(41908, '09-06-2014', 'Saturday'),
(41909, '09-07-2014', 'Sunday'),
(41910, '09-08-2014', 'Monday'),
(41911, '09-09-2014', 'Tuesday')
```

Comment: Why would you store dates in an Excel format instead of using native database formats?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Unfortunately not everyone can dictate their database schemas, but I agree :D

Comment: These are DateID's and are needed for fast execution of queries when I use them in joins and filter conditions.

Comment: @uvgoyal . . . If these are `DateId`s, then presumably you have a calendar table (or `Dates` table).  Can you edit your question and include its layout?

Comment: added relevant columns from calendar table

Comment: Hm, strange idea with that date table. So the date entries are just technical ids, and we can conclude nothing from the numbers. There is no guarantee that day 41907 is day 41906 plus 1. This makes dealing with them quite difficult. And are joins on ints really faster than on dates? I doubt that.

Comment: no the id values are incremental based on dates. If 41906 is 1st Sept, 41907 will be 2nd Sept and so on. Yes the joins and filtering was faster using ints rather then datetime.

Comment: is there any correlation the the "AM" calendar date system,  41907 happens to be 9/27/14. http://www.txdmv.gov/reports-and-data/doc_download/3383-2014-gregorian-am-julian-dates

Comment: i just provided dummy values, these are not actual values.

Comment: thats a pretty close dummy value then :)

Comment: well, I would never ever rely on technical IDs having any order or meaning. There can always be gaps. So I'd always join and calculate with the real dates, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather complicated.  Here is an approach using window functions.

First, use the date table to enumerate the dates without weekends (you can also take out holidays if you want).  Then, expand the periods into one day per row, by using a non-equijoin.

You can then use a trick to identify sequential days.  This trick is to generate a sequential number for each id and subtract it from the sequential number for the dates.  This is a constant for sequential days.  The final step is simply an aggregation.

The resulting query is something like this:

```
with d as (
      select d.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from dates d
      where day not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
     )
select t.id, min(t.date) as startdate, max(t.date) as enddate, sum(duration)
from (select t.*, ds.seqnum, ds.date,
             (d.seqnum - row_number() over (partition by id order by ds.date) ) as grp
      from table t join
           d ds
           on ds.date between t.startdate and t.enddate
     ) t
group by t.id, grp;
```

EDIT:

The following is the version on [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/431c4/8) SQL Fiddle:

```
with d as (
      select d.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from datetable d
      where day not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
     )
select t.id, min(t.date) as startdate, max(t.date) as enddate, sum(duration)
from (select t.*, ds.seqnum, ds.date,
             (ds.seqnum - row_number() over (partition by id order by ds.date) ) as grp
      from (select t.*, 'abc' as id from table1 t) t join
           d ds
           on ds.dateid between t.startdate and t.enddate
     ) t
group by grp;
```

I believe this is working, but the date table doesn't have all the dates in it.

Comment: can you please fix this portion, there is a syntax error and I cannot make out anything from this:

from (select t.*, ds.seqnum, ds.date
             (seqnum 0 row_number() over (partition by id)) as grp
      from table t join
           d ds
           on t.startdate = ds.date between t.startdate t.enddate

Comment: I am still getting the below data:

    id startdate enddate
    1    41890 41892
    2      41898 41900
    3    41906 41907
    4    41910 41910

Rows 3 and 4 should be clubbed into a single row.

Comment: @uvgoyal . . . Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: added more details in the question, i hope this is what you are looking for.